# about semantic search

Tags: search, rdf, owl, semantic-web

I am a "rookie" in Semantic Web. So a lot things confuse me right now. I am going to make a semantic web search in website. But I am not sure what should be the workflow of that?
I just have basic opinion.
Please correct me

1. use a webspider to get web resources, and put thoses reources in files.
2. parse those resource files (lexical ananlysis) and use RDF format to describe those resources (now, the RDF contains the ontologies,
   which are about resources).
3. parse the RDF files (contain resources), use OWL (combine inference mechanism) to describe the ontologies in RDF files.
4. semantic analyze the user input (from search text box), match it in OWL files, and then match in the RDF reources files, then provide
   the related results.

Please give me suggestions and correct me.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) resource for your engine.
You should learn to search and use existing resources (ontologies and more generally APIs), that allow to reuse semantic annotations on data. (Linked Data, see [here](http://linkeddata.org/)). Anyway, if you get web resources, **don't** put them in files and reference the origin, because the copy **changes** the links semantic. Knowledge evolve over time...

Regards the semantic analysis, could be a difficult task. Before you start to implement yourself, search if there is some [API](http://www.programmableweb.com/) out there, that fits your bill.